# How should esolang questions be asked?

Tags: discussion

Esolangs come in all sorts of flavours. Some of them are images. Some of them are game worlds.

Images can be embed in questions, so asking questions about such esolangs is doable. But what about game worlds and such?

For example, say I made something with Minecraft [Command Blocks](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Command_Block), and I'm having an issue with it. How would I ask a question about it?

Comment: Note that this also applies to answers.

Comment: MSE possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211565/how-to-support-questions-about-development-environments-that-rely-on-more-than-c

Comment: @rene I'm still talking about code. Just not text code.

Answer (score 2):

They should be asked like you ask any other question. You supply all the information you can in your question. If an image suffices, add the image. If it's about command blocks, there is the code you can copy, but you may want to consider a gaming-related Stack Exchange site instead. If it's a game world created in an editor, simplify it to a point where screenshots of your scene-hierarchy will do, augmented with your custom code if necessary.

If however we need to download something, go somewhere else to see what you're working with, or anything that doesn't make the question self-contained, you're out of luck.

It's [a bit of a pet peeve of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211565/how-to-support-questions-about-development-environments-that-rely-on-more-than-c), and we're  missing out on a good set of questions which are definitely in-scope, if it wasn't for the form of assets you're working with. But there is only so much we can do.

Comment: Would making a general-purpose programming language that is neither text- nor image-based oriented towards autistic people and people with neurodevelopmental disorders lead to a change? By any chance?

Comment: I guess that can only be answered in the case of a practical example. I wouldn't exclude the possibility. Generally the powers that be are very open to the possibility of change, even if it may take quite a while to implement. So if you have such an example, and can demonstrate it has or would lead to quite some interest on the site, by all means make a feature request.